# How does AggregateFunction impact State Size in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, complex-event-processing

In Flink, if we apply a FoldFunction or an ReduceFunction on a window, it

> eagerly aggregate elements and store only one value per window

See [Flink Docs 1.3](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#state%20size) for details.

Does the same hold true for an [AggregateFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/udfs.html#aggregation-functions) - because it too seems to allow you to eagerly aggregate elements and store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an `AggregateFunction` stores a single accumulator per window.

Comment: Thanks Fabian!   I am applying the AggregateFunction on a GlobalWindow with a TriggerFunction.

I understand a GlobalWindow will keep all elements it ingests.  Hence I was hoping that by applying an AggregateFunction, it will allow it to keep only one element per window - and thereby reduce state size.   

Please let me know if my assumption is correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Your assumption about the `GlobalWindow` is not correct. If you define a `GlobalWindow`, all elements for a key get assigned to a single window (in contrast a TimeWindow would result in multiple windows per key). However, they are not necessarily stored but can be pre-aggregated with a `ReduceFunction` or `AggregateFunction`. If you'd use a `WindowFunction` all events would be stored. So storing all values is not a property of the `GlobalWindow` but of the type of function that you apply on a window.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense to me now!